# what does this line make in the arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

Im checkin a code in c++ and i'm trying to "translate" it to java. i wonder what this line does... (both are int arrays)

```
          frequencies[values[i]]++;
```

and how can i translate it? 
This is the code I extrated the line from
https://github.com/Tomaszal/HackerEarth/blob/master/Data%20Structures/Stacks/Fight%20for%20Laddus/main.c

I believe it gets the value from the i-th element in the values array, searches for it in the frequencies array and add 1+ to the index...I don't really get it

This was my attempt to the code above

```
   int y=values[p];
   frequencies[y]=frequencies[y]+1;
```

Comment: seems like you understand it.... You asking how to do the same thing in Java? Did you just try to do it?

Comment: let j = values[i], let k = frequencies[j], increment k.

Comment: Yes. I'm actually kinda lost in the process...was it right?

Comment: It doesn't search for anything in the frequencies array, it indexes it just as you had understood for the values array. Then it doesn't increment the index but the corresponding value.

Comment: @Mylane you should edit in your attempt of translating it to Java, people will be able to help you alter that after seeing it.

Comment: @AndrewLohr Just did it ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets the value from i-th element in the values array and passes this value as an indexer to frequencies array and increments the returned value by 1. A perfect translation would be

> Increment the (i-th value)th value of frequencies by 1.

and it surely works the same in Java. You don't need to convert it to any other statement(s) in Java to work.